# Возвращается неверный Rect

Tags: android, методы, return, координаты

я столкнулся с проблемой:метод view.getLocalVisibleRect(rect); всегда возвращает rectangle с нулевыми координатами...что я только не пробовал...и layout_gravity,и margin,и setX setY...ничего не работает...позиция самого view меняется,но возвращаемый rectangle всё равно имеет нулевые координаты...

Comment: где вы это вызываете? где ваш код?

Answer (score 0):

создайте прямоугольник сами, получив у вью x, y, x+width, y+height

Comment: В том то и прикол...layout_gravity не менчет положение как таковове...